# Pivot Table MySQL to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, pivot-table

Hey friends I have a some problem with my query but I do not know what I am missing, Below is my PHP code to parse JSON data:

```
$supervisor='ganda.padeardja';
$sql=" SET @SQL = NULL;

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT(
            'MAX(IF(salesman = ''',
            salesman,
            ''', total_aktivitas, 0)) AS `',
            salesman,
            '`'
        )
    ) INTO @SQL
FROM
    v_dashboard_supervisor_activity2
WHERE
    supervisor LIKE '%ganda.padeardja%'


SET @SQL = CONCAT(
    'SELECT v_calendar.cdate as aktivitas,',
    @SQL,
    ' FROM v_dashboard_supervisor_activity2 RIGHT JOIN v_calendar ON v_calendar.cdate=v_dashboard_supervisor_activity2.tgl_aktivitas WHERE cdate BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY AND CURDATE() GROUP BY cdate ORDER BY cdate ASC' 
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;";//<----- .isi dengan query yg didapat .
$result=$db->query($sql) or die("Ada kesalahan query[$sql] dengan pesan kesalahan ".$db->error);
$data=array();
$i=0;
while($meta=$result->fetch_field()){
$data[$i]=array();
$data[$i]['name']=$meta->name;
$data[$i++]['data']=array();
}
$result->data_seek(0);
while($datas=$result->fetch_row()){
$i=0;
foreach($datas as $d){
$data[$i++]['data'][]=$d;
}
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

if i try this script this ouput are

> Ada kesalahan query[ SET @SQL = NULL; SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
>   CONCAT( 'MAX(IF(salesman = ''', salesman, ''', total_aktivitas, 0)) AS
>   `', salesman, '`' ) ) INTO @SQL FROM v_dashboard_supervisor_activity2
>   WHERE supervisor LIKE '%ganda.padeardja%' SET @SQL = CONCAT( 'SELECT
>   v_calendar.cdate as aktivitas,', @SQL, ' FROM
>   v_dashboard_supervisor_activity2 RIGHT JOIN v_calendar ON
>   v_calendar.cdate=v_dashboard_supervisor_activity2.tgl_aktivitas WHERE
>   cdate BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY AND CURDATE() GROUP BY cdate
>   ORDER BY cdate ASC' ); PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL; EXECUTE stmt;] dengan
>   pesan kesalahan You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT( 'MAX(IF(salesman =
>   ''', sales' at line 3

But if I try query in MySQL it's working..
[This is output query in mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djdyv.png)

And the results I expected was like this :

```
[{"name":"aktivitas","data":`["2015-11-22","2015-11-23","2015-11-24","2015-11-25","2015-11-26","2015-11-27","2015-11-28"]},

{"name":"abdul.qodir","data":["0","11","4","6","2","6","1"]},{"name":"andrinanta.putra","data":["0","4","7","6","5","0","0"]},{"name":"ganda.sls","data":["0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]},{"name":"paulus.jatmiko","data":["0","5","5","4","5","5","0"]},{"name":"sandy.wibowo","data":["0","0","0","6","5","12","0"]}]
```

Can you help me where I made ​​a mistake and miss something ??

Comment: The parser conveniently highlighted the error for you

Comment: did you change it and does it work?

Comment: my query doesn't work in php, but if i execute this query in mysql this is work